# Wiki Scraping missing data

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the table from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megacity as my initial foray into the world of scraping (in full transparency, I took this code from a blog I read). I got the program to work but instead of getting the city, I have \n (also on every field. 
Question: Why do I have \n at the end of every field and why is my first field (city) blank? Listed below is part of the code and output.

```
import requests
scrapeLink = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megacity'
page = requests.get(scrapeLink)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

megaTable = soup.find_all('table')[1]


rowValList = []    
for i in range(len(megaTable.find_all('td'))):
    rowVal = megaTable.find_all('td')[i].get_text()
    rowValList.append(rowVal)

cityList = []
for i in range(0, len(rowValList), 6):
    cityList.append(rowValList[i])

countryList = []
for i in range(1, len(rowValList), 6):
    countryList.append(rowValList[i])

contList = []
for i in range(2, len(rowValList), 6):
    contList.append(rowValList[i])

popList = []
for i in range(3, len(rowValList), 6):
    popList.append(rowValList[i])

import pandas as pd

megaDf = pd.DataFrame()
megaDf['City'] = cityList
megaDf['Country'] = countryList
megaDf['Continent'] = contList
megaDf['Population'] = popList
megaDf
```

[image: Output]

Comment: so you can get rid of the /n by using x.strip but idk about city

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help.

Comment: @dspencer please see the attached code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the city is not inside a `td` tag but a `th` tag.

```
<th scope="row"><a href="/wiki/Bangalore" title="Bangalore">Bangalore</a></th>
```

And the first td you are referring to is infact the image column.  You can select the city name by getting the `th` tag.

Also, you can simplify your crawler by first getting the rows of the table and then select the necessary tag for each row, i.e. `th` and `td`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

scrapeLink = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megacity"
page = requests.get(scrapeLink)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

megaTable = soup.find_all("table")[1]

cities = []
# [:2] slices the array since the first 2 `tr` contains the headers 
for row in megaTable.find_all("tr")[2:]:
    city = row.th.get_text().strip()
    tds = row.find_all("td")
    country = tds[1].get_text().strip()
    continent = tds[2].get_text().strip()
    population = tds[3].get_text().strip()
    cities.append({
        "city": city,
        "country": country,
        "continent": continent,
        "popluation": population,
    })

print(cities)
[
    {
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "country": "India",
        "continent": "Asia",
        "population": "12,200,00"
    },
    # and so on
]
```

You can then convert the list into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cities)
```

Comment: Thanks Rieljun - appreciate your feedback. I did not think about using an array but that is a great idea. This should work - thanks again